# jMeter on VM with no internet not finishing test

Tags: jmeter, virtual-machine, fiddler

My company is trying to use JMeter in a VM (Windows Server 2003 :( )with no internet connectivity to hit another VM with a server set up and code running on IIS.  I set up the ip address in my hosts file, let's call it server.dev for now. Our goal is to hit server.dev/doSomething  When we go into IE and hit server.dev we get a response.

We use a keystore with JMeter and it says that it creates it correctly.  In JMeter we have an HTTP Request where we hit the server.dev, and the path is set to /doSomething.  JMeter then starts, and the log has no errors, but once it says "Creating the HTTPS Trusall Scheme" it hangs.  When I put debug flags on it shows that it created the SOAP Request correctly and seems to send it out.  The Headers should all be correct.  It hangs here for about 1 minute and then shuts down with error with saying something along the lines of "Could not get response from server".

Does anyone have any ideas on where to go from here?  I tried to debug for hours, but got nowhere.  I can't seem to load up Fiddler to see the network traffic either, since there is no localhost set up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely that IE uses proxy and JMeter does not. Try other browser, i.e. [Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) (it doesn't respect system proxy settings if you won't import anything during installation) and if Firefox won't be able to establish the connection - my assumption is correct and you're sitting behind the proxy server.

There is a way to "tell" JMeter to use a proxy server, it is controllable via command-line arguments, to wit:

```
-H [proxy server hostname or ip address]
-P [proxy server port]
-N [nonproxy hosts] (e.g. *.apache.org|localhost)
-u [username for proxy authentication - if required]
-a [password for proxy authentication - if required]
```

See [Using JMeter behind a proxy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server) guide for details and [Full list of command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options) for the full list.

You can also configure proxy settings in *system.properties* file (which lives under /bin folder of your JMeter installation), add the following lines to it:

```
http.proxyHost=your.proxy.ip.address.or.host.name
http.proxyPort=your.proxy.port
https.proxyHost=your.proxy.ip.address.or.host.name
https.proxyPort=your.proxy.port
```

And after JMeter restart everything should work as expected.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on JMeter properties and ways of setting and overriding them